# AngularFire2 return 'undefined' [object Object] with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I try to get details from the `firebase` database but keep getting `undefined`
here is my code for getting the Object from the data base:

```
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase ) { }


  get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    console.log(this.db.object('/users/' + uid));
    return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
    }
}
```

the console log from this `get` method is: `[object Object]`

I can't find how to get the username or other information of this user.

Here is my AppUser:

```
export interface AppUser {
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
    name: string;
}
```

I found some answers, but it is related to older version of Angular, and is didn't help my issue.
I also saw some answer related to async pipe, but this is in the HTML, and I need the data to be available in a service.ts file.
I need to get the result in my component (not in the html).

I tried to extract the data of the user like that:

```
 get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
     return this.user$
      .pipe<AppUser>(map(user => {
         if ( user ) {
       this.userService.get(user.uid);
       }
      }));
}
```

but again the log say I got `[object Object]`...

In my final method that need to use this information:

```
canActivate() {

     return this.auth.appUser$
      .pipe(map(user => {
        console.log(user);
         return user.isAdmin;
      }));
}
```

The console log give `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`JSON.stringify`**

```
Console.log(JSON.stringify(this.db.object('/users/' + uid)));
```

Comment: I tried and got a URL to the user: {"query":"https://oshop-bf0f4.firebaseio.com/users/OWYK1oOrAwg1pxE0BLixba82nNk1"} But I need to get the properties of this user such as name, email...

Comment: you need to add this inside   where you call the get method

Comment: I did, I tried it in the `get` method, I've tried it in the `get appUser$():` method, and both gave the same `[object Object]` (JSON.stringify give the URL). When I tried it in the final method canActivate (I've added it in the original question now), I got `undefined` in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a AngularFireDatabase.
You want to subscribe to AngularFireObject. so, you have to call :

```
get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<any> { // <----
  console.log(this.db.object('/users/' + uid));
  return this.db.object('/users/' + uid).valueChanges(); // <---
}
```

and than, you can subscribe and reveal the object in your component.

--Updated--
The current object type is AngularFireObject for single object and AngularFireList for a list of objects.
You still have to call .valueChanges() to get the observable.

Comment: FirebaseObjectObservable does not exist in Angular 6 and rxjs 6. This is exactly the information that I can't find...

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check and let me know if you have any more troubles.

Comment: I've tried to add the .valueChanges(). In the console I got the same log, and I can't return it in this method. I get error:`Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'.
`

Comment: Try to log it from your service for debugging. instead of return try to subscribe inside the service and log the object. if it works, you missing something from your component(you didnt provide the full file so I cannot see it here), but if it works, it probably easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it with help from you, and other blogs. Thanks a lot!
Here is the full solution:

The user service.ts file:

```
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase ) { }

  get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
    }
}
```

Here is the Authentication service.ts file:

```
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

fireBuser: firebase.User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate() {
   this.fireBuser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   return this.userService.get(this.fireBuser.uid)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(map((appUser: AppUser) => {
      console.log(appUser.isAdmin);
      return appUser.isAdmin;
    }));
  }
 }
```

console.log(appUser.isAdmin) - give the correct property saved in the database.